# Algolia filter and query search

Tags: javascript, algolia

I have an algolia application with some objects that look like this:

```
{
  "company_id": "36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa",
  "first_name": "maryam",
  "objectID": "ffd92558-6bd3-42df-96c2-9c9124e66f6a"
}
```

I'm trying to run a query that filter search results by `company_id`.

I've read the Algolia docs and this is what I've attempted. First I added the `company_id` to the attributes for faceting in the dashboard. Now in my front end JavaScript application I'm running this query:

```
this.index.search({
  query: 'mar',
  filters: `company_id:'36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa'`
}).then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

When I run this however it returns 0 hits.

I've also tried:

```
this.index.search({
  query: 'mar',
  facetFilters: [`company_id:36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa`]
}).then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this way, more about filtering https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/filtering/

```
this.index.search({
  query: 'mar',
  filters: 'company_id:36ec09ec-6b07-45e3-ae2d-a77bfe381baa'
}).then(resp => {
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Comment: Same issue with that.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you haven't created an attribute for facet. To create an attribute, follow these steps:

1. Go to your Algoloa dashboard.
2. Scroll down to "Data source" card.
3. Click on the index that you need.
4. In the left pane, choose Configure > Index.
5. In the right pane, click on the configure tab.
6. In the new pane, click on facet on the left menu.
7. Click on Add attribute in the right pane to create an attribute for facet.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this issue as well. Looks like we need to add a facet to the attribute we want to filter. So in this case, you might want to create a facet related to `company_id` and make sure it's searchable

Comment: To increase the quality of your answer,I reccommend you add you add a clear example quoting from the question.